# Чтение текста из файла (Java)

Tags: java, android, поиск, текст

Всем привет, есть такой код поиска:

```
//считываем текст с файла
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("file.txt");
ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    result.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
String xxx = result.toString("UTF-8");
is.close();
//ищем и выводим строки по паттерну
String reg = String.format("(.*)(%s)(.*)", edittext.getText().toString());
textview.setText("");
String[] mf = xxx.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
for (String str : mf)
    if (Pattern.matches(reg, str))
        textview.setText(textview.getText()+str+"\n");
```

Не могу понять, почему при считывании текста из файла он тупо не ищет в нем совпадений регулярками, но если создать, допустим, `String xxx = new String("A\nB\nC");`, то все работает прекрасно. Пробовал менять кодировку, способы считывания с файла, но все равно нормально создает массив, а совпадений не находит (либо только в последней строчке).

Не подскажете, что не так?

Comment: @zRrr нет, просто для понимания aaa исправил на textview, а тут забыл, поправлю, спасибо

Comment: в `xxx` считывается содержимое файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
String reg = String.format("(.*)(%s)(.*)", edittext.getText().toString());
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("file.txt")));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
textview.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает, но теперь ищет только если 1 символ в edittext, если больше - нет. Не знаете в чём теперь проблема?

Comment: @Flappy сложно сказать, я у себя проверял, ищется по вхождению подстроки корректно. Надо дебажить.