# Что лучше использовать для хранения и отображения значения из файла, который мы добавляем сами в AS?

Tags: java, android

Задача: получить рандомное значение(текстовый абзац) с файла, который мы сами добавляем в Android Studio. Абзацев в файле много. Получили случайный абзац -вывели его пользователю.

Что лучше использовать для этого? SQLite, json, assets или ещё что-нибудь?

Comment: Random. Задача не понятна. Что значит передавать в Andorid Stuido? Для чего вам БД, если вам нужно вывести какой-то случайны текст, который вы сами и добавляете?

Comment: @Dred вопрос не в Random. Обычное добавление файлов в саму среду разработки, то есть в Android Studio. БД как один из способов осуществить задачу.

Comment: Я всё равно не понимаю, что значит добавить что-то в среду разработки. Может быть другие поймут.

Comment: @Dred для вас это повод ставить минус вопросу? Простите, вы как добавляете изображения в приложение через Android Studio?

Comment: я добавляю через ОС, помещаю в папку resources и тому подобное. Но это я добавляю не в среду разработки, а в будущее приложение. Эти ресурсы будут частью приложения, а не частью среды разработки

Comment: @Dred ну вы же это делаете через Android Studio? Вряд ли вы открываете на ПК папку с приложением и вручную перемещаете изображения

Comment: Именно так и делаю. Потому что я должен сначала откуда-то достать изображение, допустим из интернета. Потом копирую/вырезаю файл из одной папки и вставляю в другую. У меня не видно других папок, которые выше моей директории приложения

Comment: @Dred весьма странный способ. Технологии для этого движутся вперед, чтобы разработчики не пытали себя этими манипуляциями. Открываете проект в AS, на втором экране у вас уже скаченное изображение, CTRL + C и в drawable CTRL + V, всё.

Comment: видимо вы хотите спросить, как лучше в приложении разместить текстовый файл, чтобы иметь к нему произвольный доступ? упирать на среду разработки в данном вопросе конечно абсолютно лишнее, нет никакой разницы в данном случае, в чем именно разрабатывается приложение, работать будет само приложение, а не среда разработки, какой бы она не была

Comment: @pavlofff Давайте попробую ещё раз. Мне необходимо создать какой-нибудь документ с абзацами, допустим через Notepad, закинуть этот документ в проект в AS, далее уже получить из него любой абзац. Вопрос не в Random, вопрос не в AS, вопрос в том, что лучше подойдет для данной ситуации? Мне лишь необходимо вовне подготовить файл с абзацами, закинуть этот файл в проект и получить к нему доступ. Так как лучше всего это сделать?

Comment: @InnaM, что значит получить к нему доступ? Прочитать текст из файла? Как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564320/216510), например. Или [тут](https://evileg.com/ru/post/230/)

Comment: насколько большой объем текста, вы сами его создаете или откуда то со стороны его будете получать, должен ли он меняться в процессе работы приложения?

Comment: @pavlofff около 20 абзацев, заготавливаю его сам вовне, потом перекидываю в проект, меняться не должен.

Comment: тогда наверное самым простым, быстрым и разумным решением будет не работать с внешним файлом в любом виде, а захардкорить массив строк (каждый элемент массива - один абзац) и получать случайный абзац простой генерацией индекса массива.

Comment: @pavlofff да, вы правы, думаю это можно считать правильным ответом (не могли бы вы оставить свой ответ, чтобы я его отметила его как правильный). А если объемы огромны, как выходить из ситуации?

Comment: сам по себе объем не так важен, в любом случае в том или ином виде он будет храниться в самом приложении, а на парсинг файла потребуется дополнительные затраты. проблемнее, когда контент не ваш и вы не можете его добавить при сборке приложения (например получаете файл из сети в процессе работы приложения)

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, вы ответили на вопрос, не могли бы вы оставить свой ответ внизу, чтобы я его отметила его как правильный

Comment: позже напишу ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если текст не меняется, то самый простой и, пожалуй, удобный вариант - ресурсы) создаете обычный строковый ресурс, можно в отдельном файле, чтобы не превращать работу с strings.xml в симулятор вращения колесика(в папке values можно создавать произвольные файлы). Проставленные в файле ресурсов переносы строк aapt успешно устранит, а вот \n останутся и будут корректно обрабатываться, можно успешно отделить абзацы с их помощью. Если текст нужен не целиком - [string-array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray) поможет

SQLite представляется крайне неудобным вариантом. Готовую базу придется класть в ассеты, оттуда в рантайме копировать на диск и только из файла на диске открывать базу

json все равно нужно где-то хранить, что лишает его использование смысла

Хранение текстового файла в ассетах чуть удобнее, чем базы, но все равно придется открывать поток, копировать его содержимое в буфер и создавать из буфера строку

Если ресурсы не устраивают есть последний вариант - прописать статическими полями или статическим массивом. Но такой вариант не приветствуется, в т.ч. и самой андроид студией

Answer (score 1):

Использовать хранение в файле всего текста несколько не практично, если этот файл вы не получаете в процессе работы программы (например из интернета), так как на разделение абзацев из целого текста потребуется существенный ресурс. Гораздо разумнее подготовить структуру на этапе создания приложения. Так же нет особого смысла использовать базу данных, JSON и подобное, так как на это так же потребуется дополнительная работа. Такое решение может быть оправдано при существенных объемах текста, когда проще поручить сортировать текст программе, чем самому.

Так как вам нужно работать отдельно с абзацами, то самым простым решением вашего вопроса будет создать массив строк, где каждый элемент массива - это один абзац. Так мы сможем очень просто выбирать нужный абзац по индексу в массиве.

Для этого создадим простой ресурс (назовем его *paragraphs.xml* и поместим в папку *res/values/*). Ресурс будет содержать текст наших абзацев в формате `string-array` для последующего преобразования в массив строк. Размещение в файле ресурса удобнее тем, что не забивает сам код, так же при необходимости можно очень просто реализовать поддержку разных языков средствами самой системы.

**paragraphs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="paragraphs">
        <item>paragraph 1</item>
        <item>paragraph 2</item>
        <item>paragraph 3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Далее простой код, который по нажатию на кнопку выводит в `TextView` случайный абзац:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    String [] paragraphs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        // получаем абзацы в массив
        paragraphs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paragraphs);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // генерируем случайное число в диапазоне полученного массива и выводим на экран
                textView.setText(paragraphs[new Random().nextInt(paragraphs.length)]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Код будет в случайном порядке выводить надписи: *paragraph 1, paragraph 2, paragraph 3*